# Create documentation for websocket

Tags: go, websocket, documentation

What can I use to create api **documentation** for **websocket** server?
We use swagger for REST API, but I not find support for websockets

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use postman or swagger-websocket to generate documentation